# using neo4j graph db in angularjs website

Tags: angularjs, neo4j

i am developing a website on angularjs and my server gets information from a graph db in neo4j. At first ive used the default neo4j db (with movies and such) but when i want to load my own csv files the neo4j adds onlyhalf of them. I have 117000 rows and ive tried to use periodic commit and it added again, only 58000. What is the cypher command for adding all the data, is it ok to divide it to another csv file?
EDIT: Ive used this command:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV FROM 'http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.1.2/csv/artists.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Artist { name: line[1], year: toInt(line[2])})
```

Another question: i need to show the result from a query using angularJS and i couldnt find a normal explanation, algorithm, example etc. is there a way to show the result (the result is in json)
EDIT: i need to show the results as a table and also as a nodes (like in the neo4j admin website)

Comment: I would focus on a single question to do...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please split it up into 3 questions.

For loading data,

see http://jexp.de/blog/2014/06/load-csv-into-neo4j-quickly-and-successfully/

And check out MERGE:

see: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-merge.html

For creating an angular application with Neo4j backend

see: https://github.com/kbastani/neo4j-movies-template